# What Microsoft UI technology was used to create Zune Media player (marketplace software, not device os)?

Tags: windows, zune

UI looks like it could me made with silverlight, but it's not a web app.

Comment: Mind elaborating on this a bit? Do you mean things like WPF, Windows Forms, etc?

Comment: He does't know, that's why he is asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought it was WPF too at first, but it appears Microsoft used to a custom language called UIX (related to media center) to make it.

http://www.istartedsomething.com/20071116/microsoft-iris-uix-framework-zune/